# Are there measures for countable sets?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In measure theory, there are several measure functions for different sets, e.g. counting measure for finite sets and the Lebesgue measure. So for example the Lebesgue measure of an interval $[0,1]$ is just $1$, and the counting measure of the set
$\left \{ 1,2,3 \right \}$ is $3$.

Now, I was wondering **if there are any measures for countable sets**; seems reasonable that a "measure" for the set $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ would be $1$, but also the measure of $[0,\sqrt{2}]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ would be $\sqrt{2}$. How about more complicated sets? I was looking in some measure theory books but could not find any.

Of course, I'm thinking in bounded countable sets.

Comment: Lebsgue measure of any countable set is $0$.

Comment: [(Outer) Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure) will give the specific calculations you want. However, note that it too is coarse - e.g. it can't distinguish between $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, $[0,1]$ itself, and any other countable dense subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know, my question is if we can construct a function $\mu$ that takes bounded countable sets and assigns them a "measure" of some sense.

Comment: If $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ is any countable set and $a_n \geq 0$ with $\sum a=1$ then $\mu (E)=\sum_{x_n \in E} a_n$ is a measuare on $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$. You can find such things in almost any book in measure theory .

Comment: @NoahSchweber does it work for example for this case: if we have $f\colon [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and one wants to measure the set $\left \{ t\in [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\colon f(t)\leq y \right \}$ for some $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Would it give a reasonable measure?

Comment: @nkeLeAdo That depends entirely on what "reasonable" means. My knee-jerk response is "Yes if you only ever look at relatively simple functions, no if you try to do something fancy," but I'm not an analyst.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking for. The countable subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ do not form an algebra because they are not closed under complementation, so the usual notion of measure just doesn't apply to them.